# inner join not working in PHP, but working in phpMyAdmin SQL

Tags: php

I have a MySql Query that is not returning correct values in PHP, but if I run the same MySql Query in phpMyAdmin, it returns a value. If I display the select in a web browser, I get a 'Resource id #27' on the end of it.

PHP Code

```
$SQL_PhotoQueryList = "SELECT count(*) FROM `invoice_detail`".
                      " INNER JOIN `photos` ON invoice_detail.photo_id = photos.photo_id".
                      " INNER JOIN `invoice` ON invoice_detail.invoice_id = invoice.invoice_id".
                      " WHERE invoice.invoice_active = '$PassStatus' AND photos.user_id = '$SessionUserID'".
$SQL_PhotoResultList = mysql_query($SQL_PhotoQueryList);    
$ListPhotoCount      = mysql_result($SQL_PhotoResultList,0);
echo "SQL Query = $SQL_PhotoQueryList<br>";
echo "ListCount = $ListPhotoCount<br>";
```

Screen Output

```
SQL Query = SELECT count(*) FROM `invoice_detail` INNER JOIN `photos` ON invoice_detail.photo_id = photos.photo_id INNER JOIN `invoice` ON invoice_detail.invoice_id = invoice.invoice_id WHERE invoice.invoice_active = '2' AND photos.user_id = '2'Resource id #27
ListCount = 0
```

Code calling the routine ($SessionUserID is a $_SESSION Variable)

```
   $PassStatus = "2"; // Active
   require("get_invoice.php");
   $InfoTotalSales = $ListGalleryCount;
```

Comment: You should probably consider using [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [pdo](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) instead of mysql. But I know how these things are sometimes...
In addition, putting $variable references into your query is asking for injection.
If you separated the variables out from the query string you might find that some of them aren't defined.

Comment: $variables are all passed by me, in a calling process and not input variables.

Comment: replace dot with semicolon here: `'$SessionUserID'".`

Comment: It was the "." at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a typo.

```
$SQL_PhotoQueryList = "SELECT count(*) FROM `invoice_detail`".
                      " INNER JOIN `photos` ON invoice_detail.photo_id = photos.photo_id".
                      " INNER JOIN `invoice` ON invoice_detail.invoice_id = invoice.invoice_id".
                      " WHERE invoice.invoice_active = '$PassStatus' AND photos.user_id = '$SessionUserID'".
$SQL_PhotoResultList = mysql_query($SQL_PhotoQueryList);    
$ListPhotoCount      = mysql_result($SQL_PhotoResultList,0);
echo "SQL Query = $SQL_PhotoQueryList<br>";
echo "ListCount = $ListPhotoCount<br>";
```

Note the full stop (actually, concatenation operator) on the last line of the query:

```
                      " WHERE invoice.invoice_active = '$PassStatus' AND photos.user_id = '$SessionUserID'".
```

This should be a semicolon.  Yep, I've done that too.  Sometimes the hardest mistake to find.

The resource ID at the end is from the result of mysql_query().